# RxJS5 - skipWhile but keep values while skipping?

Tags: rxjs5

I have a stream which needs to skip while bool is true.

However, when that bool is set back to false, I need to apply the last stream value missed when it was skipping.

```
Rx.Observable
.interval(1000)
.skipWhile(val => true|false)<---when back to false, get last missed value?
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Is `val` returned from the interval operator or an external value?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Returned from the interval.

Comment: So what will you condition be like? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to give proper example , for me it is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multicast to share start and the rest values. pairwise to pairt prev and next value and concat to combine start and the rest.

```
 Rx.Observable.interval(500)
   .multicast(new Rx.Subject(), shared => {
      let start$ = shared
                  .pairwise()
                  .skipWhile((x)=>x[1]<5) // this is the condition to skip
                  .first()         
                  .switchMap(el=>Rx.Observable.concat(Rx.Observable.of(el[0]), 
                                 Rx.Observable.of(el[1])));
      return Rx.Observable.concat(start$, shared);
}).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```